# Better way to make following logger implementation thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, logging

I wanted to write a basic thread safe logger with `cout` like interface. I came up with following class design. This is definitely not the best design since it can go into deadlock if used wrongly as shown in `int main()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>  // for string streams 
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>

typedef std::ostream&(*endl)(std::ostream&);

class BasicLogger {

public:
  enum SEVERITY {
    CRITICAL,
    ERROR,
    WARNING
  };

  explicit BasicLogger(SEVERITY _s): s(_s) {
    streamMutex.lock();
    logStream.reset(new std::ostringstream);
  }

  ~BasicLogger() {
    std::cout << logStream->str();
    streamMutex.unlock();
  }

  std::ostringstream& operator<< (const endl eof) {
    (*logStream) << eof;
    return (*logStream);
  }

  template<typename T>
  std::ostringstream& operator<< (const T& obj) {
    (*logStream) << obj;
    return (*logStream);
  }

  static std::unique_ptr<std::ostringstream> logStream;

  BasicLogger(const BasicLogger&) = delete;
  BasicLogger& operator=(const BasicLogger&) = delete;

private:
  SEVERITY s;          //TODO
  static std::mutex streamMutex;

};

/*=======================================================*/
std::unique_ptr<std::ostringstream> BasicLogger::logStream;
std::mutex BasicLogger::streamMutex;
/*=======================================================*/

int main() {

  int a = 9;
  int b = 8;

  // BasicLogger l(BasicLogger::ERROR); //Deadlock situation

  BasicLogger(BasicLogger::ERROR) << "Linux" << " " << a << " " << b << std::endl;
  BasicLogger(BasicLogger::ERROR) << "MyMachine";
  BasicLogger(BasicLogger::ERROR) << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: You're probabably better off decoupling the production of log messages and the actual logging with a background thread fed from a thread safe producer / consumer queue.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Interesting idea actually. I'll definitely play around with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider only one `operator<<`, and only in that member function locking the mutex. So only hold the lock when you are going to write.

And instead of a static variable (Which is basically the same as a global variable, so you can't have multiple loggers) to hold a `std::ostringstream`, have a member variable holding a `std::ostream&`. This would mean that writing multiple things through multiple `BasicLogger`s would have them appear intermingled, but this was already a problem with multiple threads writing through the same `BasicLogger`.

To fix the problem that looks like this:

```
BasicLogger l;

// Thread 1:
l << 1 << 2;

// Thread 2:
l << 3 << 4;

// Output is one of:
1234
1324
1342
3124
3142
3412
// Ideally it should only be
1234
3412
// (Pretend `1` is something like "x is: " and `3` is "y is: ")
// (You wouldn't want "x is: {y}" or "x is: y is: {x} {y}")
```

You could have one function that writes many things and then locks, taking variadic arguments. (Written as `BasicLogger::write` in my example)

It will look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class BasicLogger {
public:
    enum SEVERITY {
        CRITICAL,
        ERROR,
        WARNING
    };

    // Consider logging to std::cerr by default instead
    explicit BasicLogger(SEVERITY s = BasicLogger::ERROR, std::ostream& out = std::cout)
        : severity(s), output(&out) {}

    explicit BasicLogger(std::ostream& out = std::cout)
        : severity(BasicLogger::ERROR), output(&out) {}

    BasicLogger(const BasicLogger&) = default;

    template<typename T>
    BasicLogger& operator<<(T&& obj) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(stream_mutex);
        (*output) << std::forward<T>(obj);
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename... T>
    void write(T&&... obj) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(stream_mutex);
        ((*output) << ... << std::forward<T>(obj));
    }

    std::ostream& get_output() noexcept {
        return *output;
    }
    const std::ostream& get_output() const noexcept {
        return *output;
    }

    BasicLogger& operator=(const BasicLogger&) = default;

    SEVERITY severity;
private:
    std::ostream* output;
    static std::mutex stream_mutex;
};

std::mutex BasicLogger::stream_mutex;


int main() {
    BasicLogger l(std::cerr);
    int x = 0, y = 1;

    std::thread t1([&]() {
        l.write("x is: ", x, '\n');
    });
    std::thread t2([&]() {
        l.write("y is: ", y, '\n');
    });
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Or you could even have an `operator<<(std::tuple<T...>)`, and instead of `l.write(...)`, `l << std::tie(...)`.

But notice the differences between this and your class. Your class will only write once, using space to have a temporary `ostringstream`, whereas this writes directly to the desired `ostream` multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

You are locking your mutex in the constructor and unlocking it in the destructor. 
Hence, it is not possible to create more than one instance of `BasicLogger` simultaneously.

`BasicLogger l(BasicLogger::ERROR);` will invoke the constructor, thereby obtaining the lock. The destructor won't be invoked until `l` goes out of scope which implies that the mutex remains locked until `l` goes out of scope.

If you attempt to construct another `BasicLocker`, your constructor's attempt to obtain the lock which isn't available until `l` is destroye leads to a deadlock.

When you create temporary `BasicLogger` instances, `BasicLogger(BasicLogger::ERROR)`, the constructor is invoked, the object is used and then immediately destroyed. Hence, the mutex which was locked is unlocked.

---

Since you are creating independent `std::stringstream` for each `BasicLogger` instance, you require a lock protecting access to `std::stringstream` so that multiple threads can write to the same logger. You should hence have a mutex held by each instance.

You also need a static mutex which protects simultaneous access to `std::cout`. The lock is obtained when the log is being printed and immediately released. Of course, this requires that all accesses to `std::cout` be made through `BasicLogger`.

```
class BasicLogger {
public:
    BasicLogger() = default;
    ~BasicLogger() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lLock(localMutex); /* the order of locking is important */
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> gLock(globalMutex);
        std::cout << stream.str();
    }

    /* TODO: satisfying the rule of 5 */

    template <class T>
    BasicLogger& operator<< (const T& item) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lLock(localMutex);
        stream << item;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::ostringstream stream;
    std::mutex localMutex;
    static std::mutex globalMutex;
};
```

Comment: I know this. I'm sorry If it was unclear but I want to know if there are better design choices I can make to avoid this problem. Correctly used this problem would not occur but I can't rely on user to always use interface correctly.

Comment: I added one way to fix your problem.

Comment: Aah. This looks promising. Just one question, is localMutex really necessary? Multiple threads writing to same `ostringstream` is not thread safe even after localMutex.

Comment: `localMutex` won't allow multiple threads to write simultaneously. If one writing is using the `ostringstream`, other threads will have to wait.

Comment: If you didn't notice, the `stream` and `localMutex` are non-static members.

Comment: Yeah but `ThreadOne`: `Object << "Thread " << "One";` `ThreadTwo`: `Object << "Thread " << "Two";`. This could produce `Thread Thread One Two` as output. Which makes one object used by two threads unsafe. Rendering localMutex as useless. Is it correct?

Comment: No, it can't. The entire stringstream output is dumped at once. That's takem care by the global lock.